# Integral calculation of the expected area of intersection of two circles

Tags: integration, analysis, definite-integrals

I want to calculte the following integral:

$$
\frac{2 \int _0^1\int _{-\sqrt{1-y_2^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y_2^2}}\int _{-1}^1\left(2 \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+y_2^2}\right) \ -\ \sin \left(2 \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+y_2 ^2}\right)\right)\right) \ x_1 \ d y_2 d x_2 dx_1}{\pi ^2}
$$

I passed this integral into Mathematica but it could't resolve it!!

This integral represent the expected area of the intersection of two circles with radius $1$, centred at two points selected uniformly inside another circle of radius $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Divergence Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem). In mathematics try to construct a visual or diagram of what you want to achieve before evaluating a complex integral. Draw these circles in 3D and use the divergence theorem or Green's Theorem.